# Assert.Pass() throwing exception

Tags: nunit, typemock, nunit-2.5.9

I have a constructor as follows

```
public class MyClass
{
   public MyClass()
   {

   }
}
```

While writing test cases, i used Assert.Pass().
But it throws an exception of type ArguementNullException

Answer (score 2):

The `SuccessException` is a convenience for a test runner. This allows you to pass a test and record an optional message. The better way to approach this is to just let the test finish without throwing any exceptions or recording failed assertions.

More info here: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=utilityAsserts&r=2.5

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake in the question. It throws an "arguementnull" Exception. i have used the same (Assert.Pass()) in other projects in my solution. Now i'm trying to use this in a console application which is a part of the same solution. is there any different approach this to avoid exception.

Comment: guys it got solved. I added a 

    Isolate.Swap.AllInstances<MyClass>().With(fakeMyClass);

Answer (score 0):

If you're using NUnit framework,

```
Assert.Pass<SuccessException>();
```

when you want to pass a test.